# Сервис рассылки писем на большое количество Е-mail адресов

Tags: рассылка, email

Необходимо единоразово отправить 1 письмо на 150 000 адресов.

Есть ли сервис который сможешь реализовать мою потребность?

Comment: man sendmail

Comment: Они все в спаме будут.

Comment: Вы в любом случае не можете контролировать работу спам-фильтров на машинах получателей. Ну разве что нужно следить за тем, чтобы в письмах не было явных зацепок для них, типа отсутствия в конвертах To: (или To: - списком). Но отправить - не вижу особых проблем.

Comment: В спам они попадут не по причине неполноценности, а именно потому-что это одно письмо и отправляется единоразово. Не все почтовые сервисы одинаково адекватны.